# Should ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone (and Time.zone)'s methods respect DST changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, timezone

Look at this code:

```
[4, 5, 6, 7].each do |x| 
  start_at = Time.zone.parse("2014.10.2#{x} 08:00")
  puts "#{start_at.inspect} / #{start_at.seconds_since_midnight/60}"
end
```

Output:

```
Fri, 24 Oct 2014 08:00:00 CEST +02:00 / 480.0
Sat, 25 Oct 2014 08:00:00 CEST +02:00 / 480.0
Sun, 26 Oct 2014 08:00:00 CET +01:00 / 480.0
Mon, 27 Oct 2014 08:00:00 CET +01:00 / 480.0
```

We are in Germany, and on October 26 the DST is reset so 08:00 is not actually 8*60 minutes since midnight but 9*60.

IMHO, this should be respected by the `seconds_since_midnight` method. Am I missing something or is this actually a Ruby bug?

Using Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.0.20 on Mac OS X 10.9.5 (MacPorts).

(Yes, Rails 3.0.20 is old. Legacy project. If it's fixed in Rails 4, all the better.)

Comment: Matt has told you why, but it's easy enough to get the right answer - start_at - start_at.midnight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-seconds_since_midnight), it's implemented as such:

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb, line 14
def seconds_since_midnight
  sec + (min * 60) + (hour * 3600)
end
```

Thus, this function is not time zone aware.  It simply looks at the local time value.  It does not consider that the offset of midnight might not be the same as the offset of the value you provided.  Nor does it consider that midnight might not exist in the local time zone (such as with Brazil's spring-forward transition).

Is this a bug?  Perhaps.  But one might also say the method is just poorly named.  Either way, it's an issue with Rails, not with Ruby.

Comment: Rails bug, not Ruby bug. Correct. I looked at the implementation too but couldn't figure out whether time zone corrections were perhaps done somewhere else. Time zones are a complitated beast. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: As general advice, consider not using Rails for time zone support.  Use pure Ruby code where you can, and use the TZInfo gem for time zones.  See the section on Rails at the bottom of [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more details.